# How to tell XCode to run IPhone or IPad Simulator?

Tags: xcode, ipad

I want to prepare my App for the IPad, but what ever I do I can not get this to work. Without any changes to the project, the Active Executable says "xxx - IPhone Simulator".

So what do I have to do to make my app run in the Ipad Simulator ?!

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the target version to iPhone OS 3.2. (The simulator currently only allows iPhone on 4.0 and only iPad on 3.2.)